# Search for strings listed in one file from another text file?

Tags: python

I want to find strings listed in list.txt (one string per line) in another text file in case I found it print 'string,one_sentence' in case didn't find 'string,another_sentence'. I'm using following code, but it is finding only last string in the strings list from file list.txt. Cannot understand what could be the reason?

```
data = open('c:/tmp/textfile.TXT').read()
for x in open('c:/tmp/list.txt').readlines():
    if x in data:
        print(x,',one_sentence')
    else:
        print(x,',another_sentence')
```

Comment: I've shortend your code to make it more readable. Could you please add extracts of both files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you read a file with `readlines()`, the resulting list elements do have a trailing newline characters. Likely, these are the reason why you have less matches than you expected.

Instead of writing

```
for x in list:
```

write

```
for x in (s.strip() for s in list):
```

This removes leading and trailing whitespace from the strings in `list`. Hence, it removes trailing newline characters from the strings.

In order to consolidate your program, you could do something like this:

```
with open('c:/tmp/textfile.TXT') as f:
    haystack = f.read()

if not haystack:
    sys.exit("Could not read haystack data :-(")

with open('c:/tmp/list.txt') as f:
    for needle in (line.strip() for line in f):
        if needle in haystack:
            print(needle, ',one_sentence')
        else:
            print(needle, ',another_sentence')
```

I did not want to make too drastic changes. The most important difference is that I am using the context manager here via the `with` statement. It ensures proper file handling (mainly closing) for you. Also, the 'needle' lines are stripped on the fly using a generator expression. The above approach reads and processes the needle file line by line instead of loading the whole file into memory at once. Of course, this only makes a difference for large files.

Answer (score 0):

readlines() keeps a newline character at the end of each string read from your list file. Call strip() on those strings to remove those (and every other whitespace) characters.