# With a dictionary, search for strings in another text file and print the entire line

Tags: python

I want to search from a dictionary if one of its words is in a second txt file.
I have problem with the following code:

```
print 'Searching for known strings...\n'
with open('something.txt') as f:
    haystack = f.read()
with open('d:\\Users\\something\\Desktop\\something\\dictionary\\entirelist.txt') as f:
    for needle in (line.strip() for line in f):
        if needle in haystack:
            print line
```

The with `open` statements are not from me, I took them from:
[Search for strings listed in one file from another text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370342/search-for-strings-listed-in-one-file-from-another-text-file)
I want to print the line so I wrote line instead of needle. Problems comes : it says `line is not defined`.

My final objective is to see if any words from a dictionary is in "something.txt", and if yes, print the line where the word was identified.

Comment: Can you give us an example (stripped down to, say, 3 lines) of what `something.txt` and `entirelist.txt` look like, and what output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific exception you asked about is because `line` doesn't exist outside the generator expression. If you want to access it, you need to keep it in the same scope as the `print` statement, like this:

```
for line in f:
    needle = line.strip()
    if needle in haystack:
        print line
```

But this isn't going to be particularly useful. It's just going to be the word from `needle` plus the newline at the end. If you want to print out the line (or lines?) from `haystack` that include `needle`, you have to search for that line, not just ask whether `needle` appears anywhere in the whole `haystack`.

To literally do what you're asking for, you're going to need to loop over the lines of `haystack` and check each one for `needle`. Like this:

```
with open('something.txt') as f:
    haystacks = list(f)

with open('d:\\Users\\something\\Desktop\\something\\dictionary\\entirelist.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        needle = line.strip()
        for haystack in haystacks:
            if needle in haystack:
                print haystack
```

---

However, there's a neat trick you may want to consider: If you can write a regular expression that matches any complete line that includes `needle`, then you just need to print out all the matches. Like this:

```
with open('something.txt') as f:
    haystack = f.read()
with open('d:\\Users\\something\\Desktop\\something\\dictionary\\entirelist.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        needle = line.strip()
        pattern = '^.*{}.*$'.format(re.escape(needle))
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, haystack, re.MULTILINE):
            print match.group(0)
```

Here's an example of how the regular expression works:

```
^.*Falco.*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tkClQMOZKFCuREUc)

Of course if you want to search case-insensitively, or only search for complete words, etc., you'll need to make some minor changes; see the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#repeating-things), or a third-party tutorial, for more.

Comment: Your second works well, the third prints something like :
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x022854B8>
Also I'm interested by searching case insensitively and for complete words, so I'll look about your link, try alone, and see what will happen :)
Thanks for helping + offer alternatives :)

Comment: @Maxim: Right, sorry, `finditer` returns `MatchObject`s, not just the matched strings. Which is a lot more useful, but if you're trying to see what's going on… well, I've edited the answer. To make regular expressions case-insensitive you can just add another flag (`re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE`). To match only complete words, if you're lucky and `\b` has the same definition of word that you want, that's dead easy; otherwise it's a little more involved. Anyway, definitely play with things using Debuggex or another regex tool, it's a lot easier than the usual edit-debug cycle with source code.

Comment: Thank you again!
How do you do it to match complete words with the same definition?
Also I would like to check if the str of the line has already be printed, and if yes, to not print. Possible?

Comment: I added :
`needle = ' ' + needle`
It seems to works on 'semi complete words'. (Otherwise, if I wrote `needle = ' ' + needle + ' '` it would not count the first (not a problem) and the last (that's a problem) word.)

Comment: @Maxim: Read up on what `\b` does. Assuming the regex definition of a word is close enough, `\bFalco\b` instead of just `Falco` will match the `Falco` in `So says Falco.` or `That's Falco's third album` but not in `The Falcon and the Snowman`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've used a generator: (line.strip() for line in f), I don't think you can access the inner variables 'line' from outside the generator scope, i.e, outside the brackets.

Try something like:

```
for line in f:
    if line.strip() in haystack:
        print line
```

Comment: Since `line.strip()` is just going to be a string (a line from the dictionary, with the newline removed), your `for needle in line.strip():` is just going to be each character in that line. So that can't possibly be right.