# Searching through a JSON data set in python

Tags: python, json

I have a flat file with data in it and I am trying to search through a JSON dataset to get back the data. Here is how I am searching through the JSON dataset with a known variable:

```
for i in get_network_json:
    if i["name"] == str(store):
        network_id=(i["id"])
        print network_id
```

What I want to do is instead of using a variable for "store" I want to pull that data in from a flat file and iterate through a file and for each line in the file print the data. I am just not sure what to use for that.

Comment: As the question stands, why don't you just get rid of `if i["name"] == str(store):`? I think this needs more clarification.

Comment: Right now I am using that statement to enable me to find what I am looking for in the JSON data set with a known variable. I want to replace that variable with whatever comes in from the file that I want to use.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't initially know the data that you want to use  from the flat file to pull information from the JSON dataset?

Comment: I know the data I have and I know the data I want, I just don't know how to write the syntax to use that data in the flat file to search through the JSON data.

Comment: Okay, sounds pretty straightforward, maybe something like [Python: search for strings listed in one file from another text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370342/python-search-for-strings-listed-in-one-file-from-another-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Give regex a shot.  It should allow you to store the patterns you're looking for in another file (presumably in a list).  You can then use os to import the file, grab the list, and iterate through the expressions to use for searching in your target file.

[Python 3.6 Regular Express HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html)

Comment: regex would work the issue is that I already the data in a file that I need. I just need to figure out the syntax to use the data in the file to search through the JSON data.

Comment: Is the data just a series of strings or a list already?  Either way you'll want to get the data into a list and iterate through a for loop so that each item in the list is searched through your data.

In that case you'll want to use "in."

That would like kind of like this:

foo = "This is a string that needs to be searched."
bar = "string"

>> foo in bar
>> True